# programatically creating regex with sed for use in gawk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to create a big regex from many options in a file, to be used in `gawk`. The goal is to find matches in lines.txt which match ANY of the options in regex.txt

File of lines to be searched

```
echo -n "dog
cat
bobcat" > lines.txt
```

File of regular expressions which will be combined into a big regex

```
echo -n "dog
cat" > regex.txt
```

I know the structure of what I am trying to do, but when I use `sed` to insert positional matching characters into the regex I get a trailing `|`.

This is what I currently have

```
rgx=$(cat "regex.txt" | sed 's#^#\\\\<#' | tr '\n' '|')


gawk -v regex=$rgx 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} {print gsub(regex,"")}' lines.txt
```

Current output from `gawk` is

```
1
1
7
```

Desired output from `gawk` is

```
1
1
0
```

Please help

Comment: Which gawk version do you have? getting 1 1 0 as expected. But the real question is - Why are you doing this? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you add a newline to the end of `regex.txt` (your example with `cat` above won't), you'll get `1 1 7` instead of `1 1 0` (where newlines are spaces). Can't really help you more since I don't have a clue what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: you could try removing the last `|` by adding sed `'s#|$##'` after `tr '\n' '|'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to also use sed when you're using awk. It sounds like you want something like:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } 
    NR == FNR {
        regex = (NR>1 ? regex "|" : "") "\\<" $0 "\\>"
        next
    }
    { print gsub(regex,"") }
' regex.txt lines.txt
1
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

@Stef's comment gets me to the desired output.

My sed was inserting a newline at the end, which was getting replaced by the `|` and this was causing the unexpected behavior.

So the working regex is `rgx=$(cat "regex.txt" | sed 's#^#\\\\<#' | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's#|$##')`

But, as Ed Morton's accepted answer shows, this can be done more elegantly using only `gawk`. I clearly need to learn more about awk!